PowerShell - get all text from file
I have text in a file and I would like to grab all the text from the file and assign it to a variable. Something like this:
$myString = Get-TextFromFile "myFileName.txt"

Is there a built in command for this? All I could find online were commands for how to parse file content into an object, like with Get-Content but I'm not looking for that, I just want the raw text as a string.

Yes, Get-Content -Raw will read your file into a single System.String versus the default System.String[] behavior.

Using this will read the entire file into the variable as a [string[]] (array).
$myString = Get-Content -Path "myFileName.txt"

To read the entire file as one [string], use:
$myString = Get-Content -Path "myFileName.txt" -Raw

To find out more about Get-Content, use the command:
help Get-Content

